# One File or Many? Creating Multiple ViewController Classes

Tags: ios, class, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a few ViewControllers in my storyboard. Lets call them:

- SB_VC1
- SB_VC2
- SB_VC3

I have one ViewController.swift file. Within that file, I have multiple ViewController classes, let's call them:

- VC_Class_1
- VC_Class_2
- VC_Class_3

Each VC_Class is used as its corresponding SB_VC's class. Each VC_Class has different code, tailored to what I want the SB_VC to do.

These are all on the same hierarchy level, none is a subview of another. They each inherit from UIViewController and import UIKit and CoreData.

**Question**:

Part 1

Is keeping the code for all three classes in one file wrong? Should I be creating a new file for each VC_Class? Or is this just a matter of personal preference? If it is not preference and is clearly wrong, what is the problem it causes?

Part 2

If all three do have a little bit of overlap, in terms of each having a few functions that are the same, should I create a fourth class and call it something like "ToolBox.swift" and use it to call those functions? Or would it be better to have VC_Class_1 house those functions and make VC_Class_2 and VC_Class_3 inherit from VC_Class_1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is a matter of preference. Though I'd highly advise against it. Large files are harder to maintain, and it will take you longer and longer to find pieces of code you need. It will also be easier for other people to read and undestand your code.

As for the common code, it depends on its nature. You can either create a `Toolbox` class or a superclass from which you will inherit.

Comment: Just broke my large file into several. You're right, it works and it's easier. I'll have to give the superclass thing a shot next.